# Why do I have to click a selectbox option twice in IE for it to go away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I have a selectbox on my page, and it works excellently in every browser except IE.  I've tested on 8 and 9, and I have the same issue.  When I click an option, the .change() event fires, exactly like it should, but the options don't disappear until I either click again (which *doesn't* fire the click event, strangely), or click outside of the select box.  This is no problem for me, since I use chrome, but I decent chunk of my users use IE8.

Here's the .change() function:

```
$('#configEquipDesc').change(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            if ($(this).val() != 'unselected') {
                ajaxGetConfig($(this).val());
            }
        });
```

Here's the HTML for the select.

```
<select name="configEquipDesc" id="configEquipDesc" data-native-menu="false" data-inline="true" class="configMenuEquip">
     <option value="unselected" data-placeholder="true">Inspection</option>
</select>
```

More options are added using ajax, and that all works perfectly.

Comment: Did you try to remove the alert ?

Comment: Haha, yes, I put the alert in just to see when the .change() event was firing.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a dynamically created selectbox, which I suspect it is, You need to use delagation. Try changing your jQuery to this:

```
$('body').on('change','#configEquipDesc', function () {
    ajaxGetConfig($('option:selected', this).val());
});
```

and see if that fixes your problem.

**EDIT** - it's the `selected option` that you're trying to get the value of, correct? Not the select statement itself. So, here's a little trick to grabbing only the selected option and sending it to your `ajaxGetConfig()` function!!

Comment: I'll try this now, but for what it's worth, it's not a dynamically created selectbox.  The options are dynamically created, but the selectbox is static.

Comment: Also, that didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion.  I like how it makes the code look, so I'm going to keep that anyway for now.

Comment: The new selector statement is awesome, and thank you for letting me know of it, but that still didn't fix my needing to click twice, haha